# Spree 2.1.1 / rails_admin 0.5.0 conflict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree, rails-admin

I have spree mounted at "/shop" (so it's admin is /shop/admin)
I have rails_admin mounted at "/admin".

My goal is to share User models, but I'm not getting past an error I cannot find any references too except an old gist from spree 1.3.2 and RA 0.1.2. (https://gist.github.com/mva3212/5570393)

The error is `SyntaxError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard"`

```
/Users/dstaudigel/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/spree_core-2.1.1/lib/generators/spree/dummy/templates/rails/application.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting $end <%= application_definition %> ^
```

The full dump is in this gist: https://gist.github.com/dts/6926855

It appears that Rails_Admin is asking for a "dashboard" blob, and spree is answering with some erb template for a ruby file (not even a real ruby file)...  Is there a way to isolate these gems from each other, so they don't conflict in this way?  Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that RailsAdmin was iterating through the whole list of models, which included a ton of Spree models, some of which caused problems.  So, I am just whitelisting models for now:

in rails_admin.rb:
`config.included_models = [ User ]`